# c# send plain text to default printer (Zebra printer)

Tags: c#, printing, plaintext, zebra-printers, zpl

What is the best option to send text to the default printer?

The printer is a Zebra, and the text is a string of ZPL.

Many examples out there are with font size, graphics, points (x,y). Very confusing.

But I need to send the string and the printer does its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the port directly using a p/invoke to `OpenFile` if you are connected using LPT or COM ports, but otherwise you will need to use the print ticket APIs to create a `RAW` formatted job.  See http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=322091 for a helper class which calls the appropriate platform functions to allows RAW print jobs from C#.

Comment: I created a dll based on the RawPrinterHelper that you linked to [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) and have used it for projects where I need to send ZPL to a printer that might be USB, PAR or networked.  It has worked really well.

Answer (score 2):

Is your Zebra printer on a network?

If so, this will work-

```
// Printer IP Address and communication port
string ipAddress = "10.3.14.42";
int port = 9100;

// ZPL Command(s)
string ZPLString =
"^XA" +
"^FO50,50" +
"^A0N50,50" +
"^FDHello, World!^FS" +
"^XZ";

try
{
    // Open connection
    using (System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient())
    {
        client.Connect(ipAddress, port);

        // Write ZPL String to connection
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(ZPLString);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // Catch Exception
}
```

I've used [this](http://z-bar.sourceforge.net/) library successfully as well for USB.

Comment: Did you try the library in my link above?  I've used it for usb communication and it works quite well.
( http://z-bar.sourceforge.net/ )